# How to use Zend2's SendResponseEvent

Tags: php, zend-framework2

In my app, I need to scan the generated output for some elements. It seems like the [`SendResponseEvent`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.mvc.send-response-event.html) would be very helpful here, as it gives me the generated content just as it would be sent. Unfortunately, the docs give me absolutely no clue on how to actually listen for this event. I tried this:

```php
class Module implements InitProviderInterface
{
    public function init(ModuleManagerInterface $moduleManager) {
        $em = $moduleManager->getEventManager();
        $em->attach(SendResponseEvent::EVENT_SEND_RESPONSE, function(SendResponseEvent $e) {
            $content = $e->contentSent();
            /* work on $content */
            $e->setContentSent($content);
        });
    }
}
```

However, it seems the listener function is not even called.

Or is there a better way in Zend 2 to work on the HTML right before it's sent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sendResponse` event is actually triggered by `\Zend\Mvc\SendResponseListener`, so you actually need to listen for the event being raised by that class. You can't do that by attaching to the module managers event manager, instead you need to do it by attaching to the shared event manager, which you can get from the module managers event manager...

```
class Module implements InitProviderInterface
{
    public function init(ModuleManagerInterface $moduleManager) 
    {
        $em = $moduleManager->getEventManager();
        // get the shared manager
        $shared = $em->getSharedManager();
        // listen to the Zend\Mvc\SendResponseListener
        $shared->attach('Zend\Mvc\SendResponseListener',
            SendResponseEvent::EVENT_SEND_RESPONSE, 
            function(SendResponseEvent $e) {
                $content = $e->contentSent();
                /* work on $content */
                $e->setContentSent($content);
            });
    }
}
```